# Where in the Dart source code is null defined

Tags: dart, null

I'm trying to understand how `null` works in Dart. As part of that study, I am looking at how null is implemented in the source code. I found null.dart in the [source code here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/null.dart):

```
/**
 * The reserved word [:null:] denotes an object that is the sole instance of 
 * this class.
 * 
 * It is a compile-time error for a class to attempt to extend or implement
 * Null.
 */
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
class Null {
  factory Null._uninstantiable() {
    throw UnsupportedError('class Null cannot be instantiated');
  }

  external int get hashCode;

  /** Returns the string `"null"`. */
  String toString() => "null";
}
```

But I can't see where `null` itself is defined. Where is it found?

Comment: As the comment mentions, `null` is a *reserved* word in the Dart *language*.  Therefore you will not be able to find a definition for it in a Dart source code file.  What aspect of the implementation are you looking for?  What happens when the compiler parses the word `null` in a `.dart` file?  How the VM/runtime handles a null object?  Something else?

Comment: @jamesdlin, since the note said that "null denotes an object that is the sole instance of this class", I thought that maybe `null` is instantiated as the `Null` instance somewhere. Maybe I am looking for how the compiler parses null, and also how the VM handles a null object. Sorry for the lack of clarity. I'm trying to understand the inner workings of Dart but my knowledge here is so low that I don't know the right question to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `null` is defined in the grammar of the language specification.

Since `null` is a reserved word (like `if`, `while` and `this`), it is not the name of any declaration. It is just an atomic expression (like `this`), and it evaluates to the "null value" which is defined as the one and only value implementing the `Null` class.

The language implementations can implement it any way they want.
The Dart2JS compiler uses both `null` and `undefined` from JavaScript as Dart null values.
The VM has a special null value object that it creates in memory as part of its start-up.